# Json Jackson Custom attribute field

Tags: java, json, api, jackson

I would like to customize the attribute labels during Rest API and POJO process. Essentially, I would like to call POST request with attribute A. But, when we store the value in DynamoDB, we want the attribute to be B. Then, when we call the GET request, we would want it to present with attribute A. Should I use @JsonDeserilize?

Calling POST request with input -

```
{   
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar",
    "A": "ownTest"

}
```

Store in the DB with

```
{   
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar",
    "**B**": "ownTest"

}
```

Calling GET request Output -

```
{   
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar",
    "A": "ownTest"

}
```

My entity class -

```
public class Test implements Serializable, IEntity<Test> {

    @Key
    @JsonProperty("foo")
    private String foo;

    @JsonProperty("bar")
    private String bar;

    private String B;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public Test withFoo(String foo){
        this.setFoo(foo);
        return this;
    }


    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Test withBar(String bar){
        this.setBar(bar);
        return this;
    }


    @JsonGetter("A")
    @JsonAlias({"B"})
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Test withB(String b){
        this.setB(b);
        return this;
    }
```

I have tried custom deserializer but no luck. Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the concept of Aspect-oriented-programming i.e. advises like @Before or @Pointcut to change the attributes while displaying the values and storing the values.

So at User-end or api-end points, it will be Attribute A and at database it will be attribute B.

To get more about AOP - follow the docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

Comment: I am limited in using only Jackson... :(

Comment: In Jackson you can do it via @JsonProperty annotation. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-name-of-property

Comment: The problem occurs when deserializing. A is not recognizable or have to store as A attribute.

Comment: Have you tried to annotate getter of B with @jsonproperty("A")?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried that. It's also not saving the attribute as B.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JsonView?
example: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation